# MYSQL Query returning column when should be value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to not show any results with the value "Money" `b.title` in the title but `%Money%` is returning:

```
Unknown column 'Money' in 'where clause'
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT `id`,`name`
FROM `users` AS u
WHERE `id` NOT IN ('
   SELECT `user_id`
   FROM `purchases` AS p
   INNER JOIN `books` b ON b.id = p.book_id AND b.title LIKE '%Money%'')
```

Comment: Don't quote your subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove extra apostrophe's:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`
FROM `users` AS u
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
   SELECT `user_id`
   FROM `purchases` AS p
   INNER JOIN `books` b ON b.id = p.book_id AND b.title LIKE '%Money%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a closer look at your query to understand what's going on:

```
WHERE `id` NOT IN ('SELECT [...] LIKE '%Money%'')
--                 |<---------------->|^     ^ ^---- another string
--                   this is a string  |     |
--                                     |     | 
--                               % is the modulo operator
```

So the expression within the brackets reads: "some string **modulo** *Money* **modulo** empty string". Without quotes around it, Money refers to a column name, which does not exist and that's where the query fails.

The only reason that you don't get a syntax error is that "%" is a valid operator. So it kind of "works" by accident.

The solution, as already mentioned: Don't quote the subquery, it is an SQL expression, not a string.